# When using VLCKit in a macOS Cocoa Application, is it possible, by updating the code of the framework, to add a gotoPreviousFrame() method?

Tags: macos, cocoa, libvlc, vlckit

I am using VLCKit in a mixed Swift / Objective-C application. VLCMediaPlayer has a convenient method:

```
gotoNextFrame()
```

that precisely jumps to the next frame of the video. Would it be possible to create an opposite gotoPreviousFrame() method, by adding it to the VLC framework just for my app ? I have compiled VLCKit successfully and did some investigation. The gotoNextFrame() method calls directly a function in libvlc, then I got lost inside the source code of libvlc while I was searching for a solution. Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to libvlc's internal architecture, having a go to previous frame function is not currently possible.

Comment: mfkl, Could you better explain why this is not possible ? Thanks